# Toolbar does not consume theme attributes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-design-library

I use theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

And toolbar looks like this [image: toolbar_ok]

But for CoordinatorLayour I need custom toolbar, not most-top-element (most top will be collapsing layout), so I use following style for Activity:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And toolbar in activity.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/ac_main_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
    tools:title="title"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
```

But it does not populated with colors from AppTheme. And looks like this

[image: toolbar_wrong]

Why? I need my theme colors and dots at the center of toolbar.

Comment: you want the given toolbar to have the second theme `AppTheme.NoActionBar` right?

Comment: No, I want toolbar to be first theme, app:theme="@style/AppTheme".
Second theme is for parent activity, so most-top-toolbar will not be added automatically.

I want manually added toolbar be the same, as default toolbar for activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found, that toolbar theme is not AppCompat theme and sould be ThemeOverlay.*

For dark action bar theme I should use

```
<style name="BarTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

not from parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

This fixes all color problems.

To fix title and 3 dots (put it in the middle of toolbar) - AppBarLayout height should be wrap_content (was fixed size before), and collapsing size in pixels should be moved to CollapsingToolbarLayout under AppBarLayout.

Answer (score 0):

try to add  android:background="@color/primary" to your toolbar definiton.
Like:

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/ac_main_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
android:background="@color/primary"
tools:title="title"
app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
```

Comment: android:background="@color/colorPrimary" for toolbar change nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Add following to your theme :

```
<!-- toolbar title and overflow menu color -->
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
```

And for the vertically center align you have to use height of toolbar as following :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/ac_main_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"    <!-- Height change -->
    tools:title="title"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't change color of dots (settings on right).
And height doesn't change because I have fixed size collapsing layout above toolbar. So i leave exact 48dp for toolbar (can change this).

Comment: I can manually set color of text, color of dots, size of text, size of dots etc. But I think good way is to fetch this settings from theme, dot re-define it for specific element.

Comment: You can check [this](https://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2014/10/28/android-changing-the-toolbars-text-color-and-overflow-icon-color/) as well.